# Stuck on an integral $4x\sin (x^2)\cos (x^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to get my head around this integral but it just doesn't click $$4x\sin (x^2)\cos (x^2) $$

I have tried substitution but I am confusing myself!

Do I substitute $\cos (x^2)$ getting $du=- 2x\sin (x^2) $ but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: The integrand equals $2x\sin(2x^2)$.

Comment: Whilst Lord Sharks answer is the most simple, your substitution $u = \cos(x^{2}) \implies du = -2x\sin(x^{2}) dx$ also works. Alternatively, you can make the substitution $u = \sin(x^{2}) \implies du = 2x \cos(x^{2}) dx$, both will give the same result.

Comment: Okay so all I need to do is substitute either of the trig functions and do the simplification.

Answer (score 3):

Let 
$$
  u = x^{2} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad du = 2x dx
$$
Then the primitive becomes
$$
\int 4 x \sin \left(x^2\right) \cos \left(x^2\right) \, dx \Rightarrow
\int 2 \sin u \cos u \, du =
-\frac{1}{2} \cos (2 u) \, du  \Rightarrow
-\frac{1}{2} \cos \left(2 x^2\right)
$$

Comment: I am not clear on where the $2x $ has gone from this answer!

Comment: @Ryan $du=2xdx\implies 4x=2du$

Answer (score 2):

$$\int 4x\sin (x^2)\cos (x^2) \,dx $$
$$= \int 2\sin (x^2) \cos(x^2) \, dx^2$$
$$=\int 2\sin (x^2) \,  d\sin(x^2) $$
$$= \sin^2(x^2) + C $$

Comment: How did you progress from each step?

Comment: @JohnLou You just gradually put items into "d", e.g. first step, put $2x\, dx = d(x^2)$. Then you deal with $\cos$, since $x^2$ lives both in $\cos(x^2)$ and $dx^2$, you could view it as a whole and get $\cos(x^2)dx^2= d\sin(x^2)$, etc. Essentially, you could view the whole process as reversed chain-rule, and it is very useful when doing integral.

Comment: Where does the $x^2$ go? It seems as if some stuff is just disappearing. Is that true?

For example, if I had $\int {2x^3}dx = \int {x^2}dx^2 = \frac{1}{2}x^4 $?

Comment: @JohnLou Yep, exactly, you get it! Not disappearing, but you view it as a whole, just like you substitute $u=x^2$, and then you substitute it back.

Answer (score 1):

The substitution $x^2=t$ gives $$-\cos^2 x^2+C$$.

Comment: Could you go into more detail for me please?

Comment: @Ryan Certainly! Let $x^2=t$. Hence, $dt=2xdx$ and $\int4x\sin{x^2}\cos{x^2}dx=\int2\sin{t}\cos{t}dt=\int d(-\cos^2t)=-\cos^2t+C=-\cos^2x^2+C$

Comment: I think i understand the first step but no so much $=\int d (-\cos^2t) $

Comment: @Ryan $d(f(x))=f'(x)dx$. Thus, $d(-\cos^2t)=(-\cos^2t)'dt=-2\cos{t}(\cos{t})'dt=2\sin{t}\cos{t}dt$

Comment: @ Michael Rozenberg thankyou for your help I appreciate it! I think I understand but have alot of work to do before my exam in 2 weeks!   This just isnt clicking for me like alot of tbings have

Answer (score 0):

$4x\sin(x^{2})\cos(x^{2})=2x\sin(2x^{2})$. Now you can take the substitution $y=x^{2}$.